# Using Nuxt Apollo to pull product detail within a Pinia Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, nuxt3

I like the idea of doing a lot of my queries in specific pinia stores as I can reuse those functions everywhere in my code however I am struggling to implement it. I have the following pinia store to get products:

```
//using composition api in Pinia
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useProductStore = defineStore('product', () => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  const isLoading = ref(false);

  const getProductData = async (id) => {
    isLoading.value = true
    try {
      const query = gql`
        query GetProductsById($id: ID!) {
          product(id: $id) {
            id
            title
            vendor
            publishedAt
            handle
            variants(first: 100) {
              nodes {
                id
                title
                price {
                    amount
                }
                image {
                    url
                    altText
                    width
                    height
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `
      const variables = { 
        id: "gid://shopify/Product/" + id,
      }
      
      var results = await useAsyncQuery(query, variables);
      isLoading.value = false
      return results

    } catch {
      isLoading.value = false
      return null
    }
  };

  return {getProductData, isLoading};
});
```

Then in my product page I try to implement the following to show the results:

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-white">
    {{ JSON.stringify(product.value) }}
  </div>
</template>
  
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
  import { useProductStore } from '../stores/product-store';
  import {useRoute } from 'vue-router'


  const route = useRoute();
  const productStore = useProductStore();
  const { isLoading } = storeToRefs(productStore);
  const product = computed(() => {
    if (isLoading.value == true) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return productStore.getProductData(route.query.id);
    }
  });
</script>
```

I do this and null always shows on the screen however the computed property i would think would be reactive and once the async function completes then it should show the value of my array. I did try console.log(productStore.getProductData(route.query.id)) and it will return the promise and show the data in the target. I am also very bad with async/await in javascript so I am not sure whats going wrong here.

Comment: No .value should be used in a template.  You can't call getProductData inside a computed, there's no way it could work. `results` should be a ref and defined as a part of store state, then you could access it directly without a need for `product`. If you want it to react to query.id then call getProductData inside watch/watchEffect

Comment: Mind posting an example of how you would do this arrangement as an answer? Would you do the watch on the query id??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems. `getProductData` doesn't use reactive data, `.value` should be omitted in a template, a promise needs to be unwrapped before its result is used in a computed.

Product data should be a part of store state, there's no need for `isLoading` state because `null` means missing data:

```
const product = ref(null)
...
async function getProductData(...) {
  ...
  product.value = null
  product.value = await useAsyncQuery(...)
}

return {product, getProductData}
```

Previous `product` value can be retained depending on the preferred caching behaviour.

There's no need for `product` computed when `product` store state is ready to be used as is in a component.

`getProductData` needs to be called at leaset once in a component, either in `onMounted` or in the body of setup when used with `Suspense`. In case it needs to react to `id` changes on the same route, there should be a watcher:

```
watchEffect(() => {
  productStore.getProductData(route.query.id);
});
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I will say though I have never used watchEffect() but rather watch() explicitly for each variable. So this is nice to learn. Do you tend to use this more than watch()?

Comment: The alternative is  `watch(() => route.query.id, id => getProductData(id))`. I prefer to list the deps explicitly myself, this is better for maintenance IME

Comment: One last question on your response. To access the data in the promise. Am I better off using await or a .then somewhere? I have only ever used axios for api requests and for that it was axios.get(...).then(response => {product.value = response.data}). Although i understand how await/async work from a c# perspective (assuming its the same in javascript) then why does doing console.log( product.value) show a promise with the following nodes target -> data - > value?

Comment: In your example you indicate I should call onMounted potentially to get product details loaded. So I run this   onMounted(async () => {
    await productStore.getProductDataAsync(route.query.id)
    console.log(product.value['data']['product']['title'])
  }) . However sometimes the console shows null for that line so makes me think I am not using async/await correctly.

Comment: async/await is 100% syntax sugar, everything that it does can be expressed with raw promises. async function is just a function that always returns a promise, and await is synchronous-looking way to write .then. I don't remember how it works in #, I believe it's sugar there too but tasks differ from promises in some way.

Comment: No, this code looks ok in this context. With something that works predictable it would be ok. It's potentially specific to asynchronous operations that are responsible for this, i.e. nuxt apollo and useAsyncQuery. I don't deal with apollo much, didn't do this with vue at all

Comment: The thing that can matter is that useAsyncQuery is a composable. Composables are supposed to be used directly in setup body, unless it's confirmed they are implemented in less restricted way. Or in the case of nuxt composables, in several other places, https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/nuxt-app#the-nuxt-context . So it may be incorrect to use it in onMounted.